# People need to read past the title?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I just asked a [question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/73947/46961)
 with a rhetorical question in the title. If people had read the body of the question they would have noticed the obvious answer to the question in the title. But they have not done so and I have received comments and down votes for that reasons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I thought for a second when I saw your original title that you might have been intending it literally. This is a fairly academic site, in which question content rather than expression is important. Therefore questions will tend to be taken literally. That probably explains the comment you got.

I think the problem people are having with your question is that the title "Was Jesus a liar?" obscures the question in your post, which is "Why is it that many Christians firmly believe that the wailing wall was part of the Temple?" People are confused about which question you're asking. That may be the source of the downvotes. Since they're anonymous, and there's no obligation to explain them, we'll never know.

My suggestions are to make sure the question in your title can be taken at face value, and also take care that it matches the question posed in the body of your post.

Comment: The title was related with the body of my post, as I explained the implications of my question

Answer (score 4):

If I could suggest something for all questions here, it is to add the doctrinal framework you're asking for to the title (i.e. according to Baptist, Evangelicals, Catholics, Orthodox, etc...).  This is the best thing you can to do ensure you get the answer you're looking for.

If you're non-denominational, this is difficult, but you still ought to have some doctrines, so you can say, "according to people who believe X, what is the Biblical basis for Y).  Questions aren't a place for flowerly language, and shouldn't need interpreters to read.  Questions must be utterly straight forward and have answers that may be divergent in conclusion, but must agree in principle.   As in, the theological axioms used to formulate the questions and the answers must be identical.

Not looking for something from Christian doctrine?  Think very, very hard about whether only God can answer your question.  If only God can answer your question, ask Him (i.e. pray about it!)